# Pintos Programming Project 2

Tags: linux, operating-system, pintos

Does Pintos have to be installed in a different way for the second Project (User Programs)? Whenever I try to run `pintos -f -q` on my installation, I get an error where Pintos doesn't recognize the arguments "-f".

```
Back to tcg accelerator.
PiLo hda1
Loading..........
Kernel command line: -f -q
Kernel PANIC at ../../threads/init.c:264 in parse_options(): unknown option `-f' (use -h for help)
Call stack: 0xc00283de.
The `backtrace' program can make call stacks useful.
Read "Backtraces" in the "Debugging Tools" chapter
of the Pintos documentation for more information.
```

This is where all the arguments are handled by Pintos:
http://www.cse.iitd.ernet.in/~sbansal/csl373/pintos/doc/pintos_html/init_8c-source.html
I can't find the definition of FILESYS anywhere either. Can someone please help me out here?

Comment: Are you compiling and running Pintos from the `userprog` directory instead of the `threads` directory?

Answer (score 6):

In `utils/pintos` change line number `259` to `/home/<your home username>/<pintos dir>/src/userprog/build/kernel.bin`

In `utils/Pintos.pm` change line number `362` to `/home/<your home username>/<pintos dir>/src/userprog/build/loader.bin`

Run `make` in `userprog`, `utils` again.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem 
You need to point the Kernel and Loader to the Kernel and Loader in userprog/build instead of threads/build as done while installing pintos